# Type definition for vite-plugin-svgr?

Tags: typescript, svg, vite

I have typescript error while adding props to Svg as ReactComponent- type is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Plugin: vite-plugin-svgr

vite.config.ts -

```
svgr({
      exportAsDefault: true,
      svgrOptions: {
        icon: true,
      },
    })
```

Added

```
"types" : "vite-plugin-svgr/client"
```

to ts compiler and I import svg like

```
import Icon from "./path"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 33):

For me i didn't create any custom file, you just need

1. In **tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": 
{
    [...rest...]
    "types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client"] <--- this line
},
```

2. In **vite.config.ts**

```
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr()],
});
```

3. In your **tsx file** in order to use it

```
import { ReactComponent as MySuperCustomIconComponent } from "../assets/logo.svg";
```

and simply use it

```
<MySuperCustomIconComponent/>
```

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75331161/7085728 worked for me. However, I used `React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }>`

Answer (score 6):

There is a declaration helper that you just need to append to your `vite-env.d.ts` file. I had compatibility issues with other solutions.

```js
// vite-env.d.ts
// ...
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

Comment: This simple solution worked for me, except one thing not mentioned in any of the answers was that you have to append "?react" to the end of your svg import, as per the [svgr docs](https://github.com/pd4d10/vite-plugin-svgr?tab=readme-ov-file#usage).

e.g.
```import MySuperCustomIconComponent from "../assets/logo.svg?react";```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on https://stackoverflow.com/a/75036507/8645558
For anyone thats trying to import svg as react component
`import { ReactComponent as Settings } from '@/assets/navicons/Settings.svg';`

you need to add export before the const(named export)

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react'

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.ComponentProps<'svg'> & { title?: string }
  >
  export default ReactComponent
}
```

Comment: thanks. that was the problem. worked for me

Answer (score 2):

To import SVGs as a react component by default, you need to include `*.svg` imports to the `vite-plugin-svgr` configuration in your `vite.config.ts` file:

```
svgr({
  include: '**/*.svg'
})
```

Then to fix the typing error you need to declare your `*.svg` module type definition **before** the `vite/client` type definitions in your `vite-env.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.ComponentProps<'svg'> & { title?: string }
  >;

  export default ReactComponent;
}

/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are exporting svg file as default and the typescript inside `vite-plugin-svgr/client` file doesn't have default declaration.

Let's try this:

- Create a declaration (`.d.ts` file)
- Add this declaration:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react'

  const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.ComponentProps<'svg'> & { title?: string }
  >
  export default ReactComponent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've ended up with:

1. Create an `svg.d.ts` file with this content:

   ```
   declare module '*.svg' {
    const content: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGElement>>;
    export default content;
   }
   ```
2. Add `/// <reference types="./{path}/{relative}/{to}/{vite-env.d.ts}/svg" />` to the `vite-env.d.ts` before any other triple-slash directives. Example:

   ```
   /// <reference types="./@types/svg" />
   /// <reference types="vite/client" />
   ```

P. S.

This is, basically, another form of vites offered solution: [link](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript)

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGElement>>
  export default content
}

/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

This advised solution didn't work for me, because while `svg` got typed, `vite/client` typings become missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I changed bundler to Vite.
Yarn install was also giving an error and saying Vite needs node 18.
So I changed my node version from 16 to 18 with nvm
then yarn install and then yarn dev. The problem solved