# Importing SVG as ReactComponent in Vite - ambiguous indirect export: ReactComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm trying to import a SVG as a ReactComponent with Vite and the `vite-plugin-svgr` plugin, and I'm running into an error that I believe to be Type-related.

Here's my import statement and usage:

```
import { ReactComponent as ProfileIcon } from '../assets/profile.svg'

export function Example() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>blahblahblah</p>
            <ProfileIcon />
        <div>
    }
}
```

The page doesn't load at all, and my browser console shows the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: ReactComponent

I think this is related to my **custom.d.ts** file, which contains the following declaration:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import * as React from 'react'

    export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
        React.ComponentProps<'svg'> & { title?: string }
    >
    export default ReactComponent
}
```

I added this declaration after troubleshooting another TypeScript error, many StackOverflow users posted the same suggestion but [here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75331161/6194904).

I can't seem to find a guide for React + Vite + TypeScript SVG components that works for me.

For reference, here's some other changes I have in place:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client"]
    },
    ...
    "include": ["src", "custom.d.ts"]
}
```

**vite-env.d.ts**

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've encountered the same error multiple times in the past. While I'm uncertain of the root cause, using the "@svgr/rollup" library worked for me:

1 Install the "@svgr/rollup" library:

```
$ npm install @svgr/rollup
```

2 Configure Vite to handle SVG files using "@svgr/rollup", by adding it to "vite.config.ts" file:

```
import svgr from "@svgr/rollup";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr()],
});
```

3 Define TypeScript type for SVG files by adding this to "custom.d.ts" file:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React = require("react");
  export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```